# GA: Where we see event tracking report?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics, event-tracking

So i created an event tracking, tested with GA analytics debugger plugin from chrome(it works) and in google analytics panel i can't find the report, is my first time with this, and i not found this on google, someone can help?

I'm in the new analytics interface [image: analytics new interface]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using a web application. It belongs on [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: sorry i didn't know about webapps.stack i go move to him

Answer (score 0):

**The Normal events overview page is located:**

Behavior > Events > Overview

**Real-time events are located:**

Real-time > events

**Intelligent Events are located:**

Intelligence Events > Overview